# InvalidSchema No connection adapters Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, request

```
def get_html(url):
    user_agent = {'User-Agent':''}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=user_agent)
    return r.text


def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pass
    

def main():
    with open('p.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as File:  
        reader = csv.reader(File)
        for url_row in reader:
            print(url_row)
            url = url_row
            get_page_data(get_html(url))
```

Mistake:

```
InvalidSchema
No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.website.com/page1/page2/']"
```

That tried:

Removed characters at the end of a line.

Reduced the type list to str.

In reality, I understand what the error is, requests cannot connect to the site, that the type of request must be a str, with a certain look, but still, can't figure it out on my own.
How to connect to the site please help?

Comment: `url_row` is a list, therefore `url` is a list. If you always want the first item then do `url = url_row[0]`

Comment: @Kemp Please write the answer in the topic below.
Your answer helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `for url_row in reader` loop `url_row` is a list of strings. This means that `url` in turn is a list and that is what you're passing in to `requests.get`.

If you know that the row you're reading in will always only have one cell or that the first cell will always be the one with the URL in then you can replace `url = url_row` with `url = url_row[0]`. If there's the possibility of empty rows then if may be worth adding a check like

```
if len(url_row) == 0:
    continue
```

before accessing it.

Alternatively, if the file is just a list of URLs and not actually a CSV file then you could read them in directly:

```
with open('p.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as File:  
    for line in File:
        url = line.strip()
        get_page_data(get_html(url))
```